# Displaying multiple values in Altair/Streamlit tooltips on a bar chart

Tags: altair

My DataFrame looks similar to this:

| name | reached points |
| --- | --- |
| Jose Laderman | 13 |
| William Kane | 13 |

I am currently displaying the aggregated count of students reached points of an assignment on an Altair bar chart within Streamlit like this:

```
brush = alt.selection(type='interval', encodings=['x'])

interactive_test = alt.Chart(df_display_all).mark_bar(opacity=1, width=5).encode(
    x= alt.X('reached points', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0, maxPoints])),
    y=alt.Y('count()', type='quantitative', axis=alt.Axis(tickMinStep=1), title='student count'),
    
).properties(width=1200)

upper = interactive_test.encode(
    alt.X('reached points', sort=alt.EncodingSortField(op='count', order='ascending'), scale=alt.Scale(domain=brush, domainMin=-0.5))
)

lower = interactive_test.properties(
    height=60
).add_selection(brush)

concat_distribution_interactive = alt.vconcat(upper, lower)
```

[Which produces this output and everything looks fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zdv3n.png)

The information I want my tooltip to show is a list of students that reached the specific amounts of reached points I'm hovering over. When adding something like:

```
tooltip='name'
```

[the way my bar chart seems to display values has now been altered to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNaku.png)

When adding something like

```
tooltip='reached points'
```

The data seems to be displayed normally but without a tooltip that gives me the necessary information. Is it possible to display tooltip data that isn't used in my x or y axis but still part of the DataFrame I'm putting into the chart?

Comment: Yes you can display tooltip data from any field in the dataframe as in this example https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/scatter_tooltips.html

Comment: @joelostblom I have found that using `alt.Tooltip(['reached points', 'values(Name)'])` does kind of the job of what I am trying to do. Unfortunately, `values(Name)` returns a list of entire rows and I couldn't find any formatting options to reduce the amount of data that is returned. Currently its something like `[{"(index)":4,"Name":"Kathleen Craig","reached points":15}, {next row}, {...}]`. Do you know about any operations to use to only display the name?

Comment: You could maybe modify it via a call to transform_calculate but not sure on the top of my head. Could you post a new question or edit this one to contain a simple [mre] that people can try? I think that will make it easier to troubleshoot this.